# How does dust get in a lens?

Tags: lens, dust

I recently saw someone offering an Nikon 70-200mm VR II lens for a good price second hand. The only drawback mentioned was that it has a little dust behind the front element.

How could this dust have gotten there, since this lens is a fully weather-sealed internal focus lens.

Comment: ALL lenses have dust in them, even before they leave the factory. If you don't believe me, maybe you'll believe Uncle Roger: [The Apocalypse of Lens Dust](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2011/08/the-apocalypse-of-lens-dust/). But beyond that, "Fully weather-sealed" does not mean what most people seem to think it means. It does NOT mean "hermetically sealed."

Comment: Related: [Is it normal for there to be tiny dust particles in a new lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/13046/15871) and [Is dust in a zoom lens a problem which should be addressed?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/3045/15871) and [What makes a camera 'weather sealed'?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/41432/15871) and [How do I avoid dust entering my camera when changing lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/30011/15871) and [Will dust inside a lens affect the image in any way?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/50415/15871)

Comment: It does NOT mean "hermetically sealed." Indeed. The new version is specified to be dust sealed too, not this one though.

Comment: Does make one wonder, why has no manufacturer tried going all motor-driven internal focus, hermetically sealing the lens and filling it with dry air or inert gas (not vacuum, implosion risk :) , as is these days done routinely eg in mid range hard drives?

Comment: @rackandboneman Because dust in lenses has pretty much ZERO effect on image quality.

Comment: Perfectly aware of that :) Was thinking of resale value :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some possible reasons:

- Intense environment (ex: The beach... especially bad if you change the lens on site)
- Poor storage (dusty bag)
- My Favorite : Zoom/Focus pump effect ! Even if it is sealed, a lens is not "a partial vacuum" ! The volume is changing, thus there is air going in and out !

For example : A lens like this old [push-pull Canon Zoom](https://kenrockwell.com/canon/lenses/100-400mm.htm) can be "weather-resistant", but with such a MASSIVE push-pull displacement, there is a lot of air entering *IN* the lens.

The newer version of this lens can stay cleaner, because many more moving parts are staying in the body. At the other extreme, a typical 70-200 2.8 Zoom like this one will not move externally at all, and thus stay cleaner.

Most lenses will at least vary on volume with focus (even primes), thus having a problem with *what* is in the air around them.

The lesson here: Don't play with your zoom in the sauna !

Comment: "Don't play with your zoom in the sauna !" Too bad, the view can be pretty nice. The zoom is a very good argument though, I forgot about about that one. Internal focus does not mean 'internal zoom'. Does that even have a name?

Comment: You are right, what I meant is that focus is *ALSO* a factor, when the focus mechanism pumps in and out of the cylinder... So not even primes are totally safe from this.